# Add a checkbox into DropzoneDialog

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, dropzonedialog

I have a DropzoneDialog and when it pops open i would like to include a checkbox on the dialog.

unfortunately this does not work

```
 <DropzoneDialog
                        acceptedFiles={['image/*', 'application/pdf', 'application/txt', 'text/plain']}
                        cancelButtonText={"cancel"}
                        submitButtonText={"submit"}
                        maxFileSize={5000000}
                        filesLimit={1}
                        open={openUpload}

                        onClose={() => setUploadOpen(false)}
                        onSave={(files) => {
                            const reader = new FileReader();
                            reader.addEventListener('load', async () => {
                               
                            });
                            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(files[0]);
                        }}
                        showPreviews={true}
                        showFileNamesInPreview={true}
                    >
                        <FormControlLabel
                            control={
                                <Checkbox
                                    name="IsInvoice"
                                    color="primary"
                                />
                            }
                            label="Is Invoice"
                        /> 
                    </DropzoneDialog>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the source code ([DropzoneDialog](https://github.com/Yuvaleros/material-ui-dropzone/blob/master/src/components/DropzoneDialog.js), [DropzoneAreaBase](https://github.com/Yuvaleros/material-ui-dropzone/blob/master/src/components/DropzoneAreaBase.js)), these don't handle the children components, so it won't be able for you to include a checkbox. Or you could if you fork the package and modify at your own risk.

A better solution I think, is that you should have a look at [React Dropzone](https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone), and try to combine it with MaterialUI's [Dialog](https://material-ui.com/components/dialogs/)